# Wordpress - display the page content without <p> wrapper

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to display the content for given page ID withot the `<p></p>` wrapper?

The method I'm currently using is:

```
<?php 
$id=21; 
$post = get_page($id); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $content;  
?>
```

For example `page ID = 21` has the following content: `Some content`

What the wordpress echo is `<p>Some content</p>`

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want the surrounding paragraph tags echoed, just remove the filter by adding  `<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>` to your template page.